# What is the unknown angle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles, triangulation

[image]

So first off I started with the pythagorean theorem to find the missing leg of the triangle. 
\begin{align*}
5^2 + b^2 ={}& 8^2 \\
25 + b^2 ={}& 64 \\
64 - 25 ={}& 39 \\
\text{missing leg}={}&\sqrt{39} = 6.244 \\
\end{align*}

Taking the 6.244 as the opposite leg of the triangle to the angle at the top of the triangle, using sin = opposite / hypotenuse 
\begin{align*}
\sin (\text{angle}) ={}& 6.244 / 8 \\
\text{angle} ={}& \arcsin (0.7805) = 51.3064\text{˚}.
\end{align*}
If I'm on the right track, where do I go from here to find the unknown angle?

Comment: The acute angles in a right triangle are complementary.  Look at the largest of the three right triangles in the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sin(\theta)=\frac{5}{8}$ because

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Answer (score 0):

HINT : The two small triangles are similar. (You don't need to find the lengths of other sides.)

Answer (score 0):

You are on track. Answer is complement of what you got, ~ 90-51.3 deg.